# exponential generating function for the number of ways to arrange marbles in a line

Tags: combinatorics, exponential-function, generating-functions

Say we have red, green, and blue marbles that we are arranging in a line of length n. We need to use an even number of blue marbles, at least two red marbles, and at most two green marbles. I am trying to count the number of total colourings using an exponential generation function:
$\phi(t)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{f_nt^n}{n!}$ where $f_n$ is the number of total colourings.

The problem that I am running into with this question is that I also need to arrange the marbles once I select them. I believe I can select them with the egf:

$(\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{t^{2n}}{2n!})(\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{t^{n}}{n!})(1/0!+t/1!+t^2/2!)=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}*(e^t-1-t)*(1+t+t^2/2)$

Am I on the wrong track?

Comment: The fact that you’re using *exponential* generating functions already takes into account the selection process. What you have would be fine, except that the first factor should be $\frac12(e^t+e^{-t})$; what you have gives the odd-numbered terms.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I've edited my mistake.

Comment: Looks okay now.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott "The fact that you’re using exponential generating functions already takes into account the selection process." Okay, how should I go about arranging them in the line once I've selected them? Since there are duplicates, I can't simply multiply by n!

Comment: You don’t need to do anything: the exponential g.f. takes care of that. (Perhaps it would have been clearer had I said *the selection and ordering*.)

Comment: Ahh okay. I suppose that is related to the fact that we are dividing by k! for each t^k term.

Comment: It works because the the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in the product of $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)$ and $\sum_{n\ge 0}b_n\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}ka_kb_{n-k}$$ instead of $$\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\;,$$ as it would be with ordinary g.f.s. That binomial coefficient is what does the trick.